# Second instance of script runs the exact same code as the first one

Tags: php

This script is supposed to write log files using file locks etc to make sure that scripts running at the same time don't have any read/write complications. I got it off someone on php.net. When I tried to run it twice at the same time, I noticed that it completely ignored the lock file. However, when I ran them consecutively, the lock file worked just fine.

That doesn't make any sense whatsoever. The script just checks if a file exists, and acts based on that. Whether another script is running or not, shouldn't influence it at all. I double checked to make sure the lock file was created in both cases; it was.

So I started to do some testing.

First instance started at `11:21:00` outputs:

```
Started at: 2012-04-12 11:21:00 
Checking if weblog/20120412test.txt.1.wlock exists
Got lock: weblog/20120412test.txt.1.wlock
log file not exists, make new
log file was either appended to or create anew
Wrote: 2012-04-12 11:21:00 xx.xx.xx.xxx "testmsg" 
1
```

Second instance started at `11:21:03` outputs:

```
Started at: 2012-04-12 11:21:00 
Checking if weblog/20120412test.txt.1.wlock exists
Got lock: weblog/20120412test.txt.1.wlock
log file not exists, make new
log file was either appended to or create anew
Wrote: 2012-04-12 11:21:00 xx.xx.xx.xxx "testmsg" 
1
```

So there are two things wrong here. The timestamp, and the fact that the script sais the lock file doesn't exist even though it most certainly does.

It's almost as if the second instance of the script simply outputs what the first one did.

```
<?php
function Weblog_debug($input)
{
    echo $input."<br/>";
}
function Weblog($directory, $logfile, $message)
{
    // Created 15 september 2010: Mirco Babin
    $curtime = time();

    $startedat = date('Y-m-d',$curtime) . "\t" . date('H:i:s', $curtime) .  "\t";
    Weblog_debug("Started at: $startedat");

    $logfile = date('Ymd',$curtime) . $logfile;

    //Set directory correctly
    if (!isset($directory) || $directory === false)
    $directory = './';
    if (substr($directory,-1) !== '/')
    $directory = $directory . '/';

    $count = 1;
    while(1)
    {
        //*dir*/*file*.*count*
        $logfilename = $directory . $logfile . '.' . $count;

        //*dir*/*file*.*count*.lock
        $lockfile = $logfilename . '.wlock';
        $lockhandle = false;
        Weblog_debug("Checking if $lockfile exists");
        if (!file_exists($lockfile))
        {
            $lockhandle = @fopen($lockfile, 'xb'); //lock handle true if lock file opened
            Weblog_debug("Got lock: $lockfile");
        }
        if ($lockhandle !== false) break; //break loop if we got lock

        $count++;
        if ($count > 100) return false;
    }

    //log file exists, append
    if (file_exists($logfilename))
    {
        Weblog_debug("log file exists, append");
        $created   = false;
        $loghandle = @fopen($logfilename, 'ab');
    }
    //log file not exists, make new
    else
    {
        Weblog_debug("log file not exists, make new");
        $loghandle = @fopen($logfilename, 'xb');
        if ($loghandle !== false) //Did we make it?
        {
            $created = true;

            $str = '#version: 1.0' . "\r\n" .
            '#Fields: date time c-ip x-msg' . "\r\n";
            fwrite($loghandle,$str);
        }
    }

    //was log file either appended to or create anew?
    if ($loghandle !== false)
    {
        Weblog_debug("log file was either appended to or create anew");
        $str = date('Y-m-d',$curtime) . "\t" . 
        date('H:i:s', $curtime) .  "\t" .
        (isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) ? $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] : '-') . "\t" .
        '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $message) . '"' . "\r\n";
        fwrite($loghandle,$str);

        Weblog_debug("Wrote: $str");

        fclose($loghandle);
        //Only chmod if new file
        if ($created) chmod($logfilename,0644); // Read and write for owner, read for everybody else

        $result = true;
    }
    else
    {
        Weblog_debug("log file was not appended to or create anew");
        $result = false;
    }

    /**
    Sleep & disable unlinking of lock file, both for testing purposes.
    */
    //Sleep for 10sec to allow other instance(s) of script to run while this one still in progress.
    sleep(10);
    //fclose($lockhandle);
    //@unlink($lockfile);

    return $result;
}

echo Weblog("weblog", "test.txt", "testmsg");
?>
```

**UPDATE:**

Here's a simple script that just shows the timestamp. I tried it on a different host so I don't think it's a problem with my server;

```
<?php
function Weblog_debug($input)
{
    echo $input."<br/>";
}
$curtime = time();
$startedat = date('Y-m-d',$curtime) . "\t" . date('H:i:s', $curtime) .  "\t";
Weblog_debug("Started at: $startedat");

$timediff = time() - $curtime;
while($timediff < 5)
{
    $timediff = time() - $curtime;
}

Weblog_debug("OK");
?>
```

Again, if I start the second instance of the script while the first is in the while loop, the second script will state it started at the same time as the first.

Answer (score 0):

I can't fricking believe this myself, but it turns out this is just a "feature" in Opera. The script works as intended in Firefox. I kinda wish I tested that before I went all berserk on this but there ya go.